# RxJava 2 / Retrofit 2 call not being made

Tags: java, android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am trying to sync all local data with the data on the server so i am fetching all local data and for anything other than local data i am making a call to the server to fetch the rest of the data.

```
public Observable<List<Chat>> getChats(int userId) {

    Log.i("chatRequest", TAG);

    return Observable.merge(chatDiskData.getChats(), chatDiskData.getChats().flatMap(new Function<RealmResults<Chat>, ObservableSource<List<Chat>>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableSource<List<Chat>> apply(@NonNull RealmResults<Chat> chats) throws Exception {

            Log.i("chatRequest", TAG + "  inside");

            ArrayList<String> chatIds = new ArrayList<>();
            HashMap<String, Long> chatsTimeStamp = new HashMap<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < chats.size(); i++) {
                String chatId = chats.get(i).getChat_id();
                chatIds.add(chatId);

                long timestamp = chatDiskData.lastMessage(chatId);
                chatsTimeStamp.put(chatId, timestamp);
            }

            return chatCloudData.getChats(userId, chatIds, chatsTimeStamp).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .doOnNext(chats1 -> Log.i("chatRequest", TAG + "  inside  inside"));
        }
    }));
}
```

ChatCloudData

```
public Observable<List<Chat>> getChats(int userId, ArrayList<String> 
    chatIds, HashMap<String, Long> chats) {

    Log.i("chatRequest", TAG);

    ChatsRequest chatsRequest = new ChatsRequest.Builder(userId)
            .chatIDs(chatIds)
            .chats(chats)
            .build();

    return apiService.getChats(chatsRequest);
}
```

Endpoint

`@POST("Chat/sync")
    Observable<List<Chat>> getChats(@Body ChatsRequest chatsRequest);`

The output it as follows

`03-11 22:44:45.430 31540-31540/com.project I/chatRequest: com.project.ChatFragment
03-11 22:44:45.430 31540-31540/com.project I/chatRequest: com.project.Repository.ChatRepository
03-11 22:44:45.430 31540-31540/com.project I/chatRequest: com.project.Repository.ChatDiskData  getChats
03-11 22:44:45.436 31540-31540/com.project I/chatRequest: com.project.Repository.ChatDiskData  getChats
03-11 22:44:45.442 31540-31815/com.project I/chatRequest: com.project.Repository.ChatRepository  inside`

Why isn't the getChats method of cloudData being called?

Comment: you mean the method `chatCloudData.getChats...)` from the return statement in the overridden method `@Override
        public ObservableSource<List<Chat>> apply(@NonNull RealmResults<Chat> chats) throws Exception`?

Comment: @Alex yes that one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should precise on that scheduler you want to emit your value :

```
return chatCloudData.getChats(userId, chatIds, chatsTimeStamp).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(relevantScheduler)
                    .doOnNext(chats1 -> Log.i("chatRequest", TAG + "  inside  inside"));
```

EDIT:

```
public Observable<List<Chat>> getChats(int userId) {

    Log.i("chatRequest", TAG);

    return Observable.merge(chatDiskData.getChats(), chatDiskData.getChats().flatMap(new Function<RealmResults<Chat>, ObservableSource<List<Chat>>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableSource<List<Chat>> apply(@NonNull RealmResults<Chat> chats) throws Exception {

            Log.i("chatRequest", TAG + "  inside");

            ArrayList<String> chatIds = new ArrayList<>();
            HashMap<String, Long> chatsTimeStamp = new HashMap<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < chats.size(); i++) {
                String chatId = chats.get(i).getChat_id();
                chatIds.add(chatId);

                long timestamp = chatDiskData.lastMessage(chatId);
                chatsTimeStamp.put(chatId, timestamp);
            }

            return Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<List<Chat>>() {
                @Override
                public List<Chat> call() throws Exception {
                    return chatCloudData.getChats(userId, chatIds, chatsTimeStamp).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .doOnNext(chats1 -> Log.i("chatRequest", TAG + "  inside  inside"));
                }
            });
        }
    }));
}
```

ChatCloudData

```
public List<Chat> getChats(int userId, ArrayList<String> 
    chatIds, HashMap<String, Long> chats) {

    Log.i("chatRequest", TAG);

    ChatsRequest chatsRequest = new ChatsRequest.Builder(userId)
            .chatIDs(chatIds)
            .chats(chats)
            .build();

    return apiService.getChats(chatsRequest);
}
```

Endpoint

```
@POST("Chat/sync")
    List<Chat> getChats(@Body ChatsRequest chatsRequest);
```

Hope this helps.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: I tried observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) it didnt work

Comment: Have you try to set a okhttp client with a loginintercerptor to see if is not request issue ?

Comment: Yes i have done that,its not a request issue because if i individually call chatCloudData.getChats(userId, chatIds, chatsTimeStamp).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .doOnNext(chats1 -> Log.i("chatRequest", TAG + "  inside  inside")); it works but when i put it in the return method it does not

Comment: So ObservableSource<List<Chat>> observable = hatCloudData.getChats(userId, chatIds, chatsTimeStamp).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(relevantScheduler)
                    .doOnNext(chats1 -> Log.i("chatRequest", TAG + "  inside  inside"));

return observable;

Work ?

Comment: Yes it does when i make just that call.

Comment: Weird, maybe you can try to return List<Chat> on your api service and return a Observable.fromCallable in your merge...

Comment: Could you show me in code what you meant please,i didn't entirely follow.

Comment: I found the problem in the calls being made within the merge,since i was using realm it was performing the operation on a different thread and was throwing an error which i left unchecked.I used observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) for each diskData call and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
return Observable.merge(chatDiskData.getChats().observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()),
            chatDiskData.getChats().observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .flatMap(new Function<RealmResults<Chat>, ObservableSource<List<Chat>>>() {
                        @Override
                        public ObservableSource<List<Chat>> apply(@NonNull RealmResults<Chat> chats) throws Exception {

                            Log.i("chatRequest", TAG + "  inside");

                            ArrayList<String> chatIds = new ArrayList<>();
                            HashMap<String, Long> chatsTimeStamp = new HashMap<>();

                            for (int i = 0; i < chats.size(); i++) {
                                String chatId = chats.get(i).getChat_id();
                                chatIds.add(chatId);

                                long timestamp = chatDiskData.lastMessage(chatId);
                                chatsTimeStamp.put(chatId, timestamp);
                            }

                            return chatCloudData.getChats(userId, chatIds, chatsTimeStamp).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                    .doOnNext(chats1 -> Log.i("chatRequest", TAG + "  inside  inside"));
                        }
                    }));
```

The .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() was the important part as i was using realm and it was fetching data on a different thread.